# Does Facebook have a paid Graph API access?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Does Facebook have a paid Graph API which exposes more functionality/tweets/posts?
I wonder if there is paid unlimited Graph API access

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no special 'paid' API which gives more data than the otherwise public APIs